# Getting values out of an array of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have an array of NSDictionary.  My NSDictionary are essentially small and look like

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fname, @"FName", lname, "@LName", img, @"Image", nil];
```

I have this because I need to store an image with its name, and depending on the sort order, I need to keep the pictures coinciding with the name for my UITableView.  So after I resort my array by fname or lname, I'm trying to get the @"Image" out from the dictionary in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  How do I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: You mean [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"Image"] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your index path to retrieve the dictionary in the array :

```
NSDictionary *d = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then get the object for the key @"Image" :

```
id obj = [d valueForKey:@"Image"];
```

If you know the type for `obj`, use it instead of `id`.

Comment: i didn't have any table view then how s'd i used indexPath.

I just have this array and dictionary in viewdidload